# Wordpress how to get "label" of custom fields

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-wordpress-pages, custom-fields

I have this code to get the value for custom field `myCustomField` which works fine:

```
get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'myCustomField', true )
```

This code gets the value stored in this field.

But now I need a code to **dynamically** get and echo the Custom field **label** (not the stored value) which is "My Custom Field".

This code will be fired for this action:

```
add_action('woocommerce_product_meta_start' , 'add_in_product_page');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've created your custom field using ACF plugin, then what you need is the `field object`. You could call `get_field_object` function in order to get the object and then find the label returned in the object, like so:

```php
$your_field_name = "your_custome_field_name"; 

$your_field_object = get_field_object($your_field_name); // You could also pass the field key instead of field name   


echo $your_field_object['label']; 
echo "<br>";  
echo $your_field_object['value'];
echo "<br>";  
echo $your_field_object['key'];
echo "<br>";  
echo $your_field_object['type'];
echo "<br>";  
echo $your_field_object['ID'];
```

You could also read more about this function on the documentation page:

> [ACF `get_field_object` function](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field_object/)

---

**UPDATE**

Translating the returned label to your local language!

I would usually use these two filter hooks: `gettext` and `ngettext`.

You could read more about these on the documentation page:

> [WordPress `gettext` filter hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/gettext/)
> [WordPress `ngettext` filter hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/ngettext/)

So the translation would be something like this:

```php
$awesome_label = $your_field_object['label'];

add_filter('ngettext', 'your_theme_custom_translation', 20, 3);
add_filter( 'gettext', 'your_theme_custom_translation', 20, 3 );

function your_theme_custom_translation( $translated, $text, $domain ) {
  if ( ! is_admin() ) {
    if ( $awesome_label == $translated ){
      $translated = 'etiqueta impresionante'; // This is the place where you could type anything you want in your local language to replace the default english label
    }
  }
  return $translated;
}
```

Comment: Your code works, but I forgot to mention that I translated the custom fields using WPML. Then, your code echo only the default value for 'label'. Is there a way to get the value in the right language.

Comment: Yes there is. I would usually use ```gettext``` and ```ngettext``` filter hooks to do the translations for me. Are you familiar with those or you want me to show it to you?

Comment: Yes please, show me how to use gettext and nget text. I just accepted your answer ;)

Comment: Not a WordPress function and only works with ACF